# Can't add weblogic 12.2.1.4 server to eclipse photon June 2018

Tags: eclipse, server, weblogic12c, eclipse-photon

When I am trying to add the runtime environment for weblogic 12.2.1.4 eclipse gives me no error but I am not able to proceed further. I have downloaded the latest version of eclipse from oracles website. It gives a warning "No applicable extensions found"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sraRf.png)

Comment: Eclipse Photon is actually 2 years and 9 releases old, try the latest Eclipse 2020-09

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but in my current organisation we use some plugins which are not available in the versions after photon I am bound to use eclipse photon.

Comment: @vijay Please try the current Eclipse version to verify that the root cause is your outdated Eclipse.

Comment: @howgler I tried the latest eclipse but the weblogic plugin is not compatible with latest eclipse version

Comment: You have to set your java home to complete the configuration.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin Tried that as well but no luck, if I dont mention java home then by default it should take it from the Java Runtime right?